# Bounds (or model) for estimating probability from generating process

Tags: probability, graphical-model, bounds

I was curious if there was any bounds or approaches to getting good estimates for a probability from the following generating process.

Suppose we have 2 sets of objects $A$ and $B$ where both sets are large and possibly infinite. The generating process is that $a \in A$ is drawn from a categorical distribution over $A$. $a$ then dictates another categorical distribution over $B$ from which a $b$ is drawn.

From this scenario I would like to estimate P($b_i$ | $b_j$) = $\sum_{a \in A} P(b_i | a) P(a | b_j)$. In other words given that $b_j$ has been generated what is the probability that $b_i$ could have been generated instead?

I am interested in either some bounds or procedures that could help me estimate this by sampling enough $a$. If someone is familiar with a model that could be used in this situation that would be awesome as well.